# Machine learning goal: given a population of 100,000 students, predict a group of 3,000, and minimize the median grade of that group

Tags: python, classification, regression, reinforcement-learning, xgboost

In other words, I am looking to predict students that will fail out of school before it happens. The data includes socioeconomic status and other related variables.

I have tried an XGB binary classification (both tree and forest), but the problem is that it doesn't penalize severely wrong answers (predicting that a student will be in the bottom 3% in terms of grades, but they're actually A+ students). The result is that the average grades of the predicted students is quite low, but the median grades aren't actually that bad - there are a few extremely bad students that pull down the average but not the median.

I have tried a XGB regression (both tree and forest), but the problem is that I can't get the model to focus on the bottom 3%. It seeks to reduce error for all predictions. I couldn't care less about telling the difference between an A student and a B student, I only need to consistently identify the bottom 3%ile.

I was thinking that perhaps this could lend itself to reinforcement learning instead of supervised, but I know nothing about reinforcement... WOuld it be possible to make a reinforcement model where the goal is to minimize the median grades of the 3% of students predicted? Or are there any other machine learning techniques that would work?

Comment: What kind of data do you have?

Comment: 62 features either binary or percentiles.

Comment: Maybe worth looking at modeling “rare events” approach ? I do think suits your problem here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing a custom loss function for a regression model!

Keras' neural networks support this, for example. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/43818584/745868

(But many other libraries give support for this as well)

The only special thing about your custom loss function is that it doesn't add up the error of a datapoint if min(pred_y, actual_y) >= THRESHOLD

Comment: Do you have any links that could help me create a loss function? I have no idea how to... eg. for XGB they have to have gradient and hessian which I don't think is possible for median / min functions?

Comment: holy crap I just realized how genius this is. I can just take the normal loss function and then exclude any datapoints that aren't in the bottom 3%ile?????????

Comment: Yes, exactly. Here's an example: https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/how-to-create-a-custom-loss-function-in-keras-637bd312e9ab. Please let me know if you bumped into a wall

Comment: I would not exclude everything not at the bottom 3%. You also need to worry about mislabelling an A student as a bottom 3% one ;)

Comment: Ahhh ok understood. Is there a way to see the default objective function codes so I can start there and add my threshold?

Comment: Sure, you can start from here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py. But the link of my other comment also has a useful example. Feel free to tell me how your model performed! :-)

Comment: I have not been able to make the custom objective function. I tried ranking the predictions and removing any rows in the pred_y, actual_y arrays, but that doesn't work. I'm not sure what to do to make it not add the errors... if pred_y, actual_y<= threshold, I set them both to zero? If i remove them completely I get an error that the gradient vector size =/= input data size.

Comment: Then get inspired by this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51312070/745868. Create the appropriate mask and then do a pairwise multiplication

Comment: Read also this link https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/less